# Insert into Order table where customer_id is taken from Customer table where login == session

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I don't know how to do this.

When user bought all products i wanna insert it into Orders table, additionally i wanna insert there customer_id from Customer table where user login = Session["id"]. I tried this but it didn't work :/ What should i do?

```
protected void ConfirmPurchase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["id"] != null)
    {
        string username;
        username = Convert.ToString(Session["id"]);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SOME_SQL;Initial Catalog=Shop;Integrated Security=True");

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (order_date, paid, transact_status, customer_id) VALUES (GETDATE() ,'" + cost.ToString("c") + "' ,'Przyjęto do bazy', SELECT customer_id FROM Customer WHERE login='" + username + "')", con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Redirect("Payment/Payment.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("InputPersonalData.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it actually need to be in one query?

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Instead of one query, `Trigger` might be the solution.

Comment: You probably need brackets around `SELECT customer_id FROM Customer WHERE login='" + username + "'` in the SQL statement. One way to check this is to get the *exact* string being passed to the SqlCommand and try to run it interactively. You'll see what errors it generates more easily. Either that or add in a `try...catch` block and trap the exception and check the details there.

Comment: Error Message:ncorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Opis: Podczas wykonywania bieżącego żądania sieci Web wystąpił nieobsługiwany wyjątek. Aby uzyskać dodatkowe informacje o błędzie i miejscu jego występowania w kodzie, przejrzyj ślad stosu. 

Szczegóły wyjątku: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: IIRC the `VALUES(..)` clause of the `INSERT` statement does *not* allow subqueries (`SELECT ...`).  Changing the `INSERT .. VALUES(..)` clause to an `INSERT .. SELECT ..` should fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by surrounding the user select with "(" and ")"

Instead of

```
SELECT customer_id FROM Customer WHERE login='" + username + "'
```

use

```
( SELECT customer_id FROM Customer WHERE login='" + username + "' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are combining the two flavors of INSERT, INSERT ... VALUES and INSERT ... SELECT; the easiest option in my opinion is to do it through an INSERT ... SELECT:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (order_date, paid, transact_status, customer_id) SELECT GETDATE() ,'"
   + cost.ToString("c") 
   + "' ,'Przyjęto do bazy', customer_id FROM Customer WHERE login='"
   + username + "'", con);
```

Then, it is a good practice to use parameterized queries, preventing risks like SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put the `subselect` into brackets:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (order_date, paid, transact_status, customer_id) VALUES (GETDATE() ,'" + cost.ToString("c") + "' ,'Przyjęto do bazy', (SELECT customer_id FROM Customer WHERE login='" + username + "'))", con);
```